# Creating Google Location URL by using latitude & longtitude pairs

Tags: android

I have a code where I'm retrieving latitude and longtitude information. I'm wondering what tools I need on hand in order to create a google maps URL.

I'm not interested to show that information on map but I would like to be able to create a link (Google Maps URL for latitude and longtitude info). Is that possible? If yes, I appreciate if you can direct me what tools I need in order to achieve that functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is to construct the URL yourself.  For example, for the coordinates 35.17380831799959,-86.1328125 (lat is first, lon is second), the following URL will work http://maps.google.com/?q=35.17380831799959,-86.1328125

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll just output a URL with the formatting of q=lat,lng:

http://maps.google.com/?q=latitude,longitude

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Google Static maps API, they have examples of constructing links

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/